# How do you connect Flash Builder CS5 to IIS & Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, iis, flash-builder

I'm having problems understanding exactly how you connect a Flash Builder 4 Project to IIS & subsequently, sql server.  In trying to configure the Flash Builder 'Server', no matter what I put in as 'web application root' and 'Web application URL' and 'Output Folder' it won't validate my configuration.

The documentation is maddeningly nebulous - does anyone have a straightforward step by step on how to accomplish this?  I'm trying to insert two bits of data into a simple table.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had maddening issues with this topic.

What I've found that works is,

Open your `.flexProperties` file (located at the project root),

and change the

```
  serverRoot="<<path>>"
  serverRootURL="<<URL>>"
```

properties to match what you want the "Web application root" and "Web application URL" to be

You'll do the same with the `.actionScriptProperties` file, changing the

```
  outputFolderLocation="<<path>>"
```

property to match the "Output folder" to be.

In my experience, `<<path>>` is the same physical path in both instances, though I expect that isn't always the case.  It is just the path where the compiled application files should be placed (since they need to be put somewhere that the webserver can properly serve!), and likewise, the `<<URL>>` is just the servers reference to that same file location, in URL format, so that when you click "RUN" or "DEBUG", FB knows where to tell the browser to go to see the newest incarnation.

I've never figured out why the configuration doesn't validate, but this workaround definitely does the job.

HTH!